# не работают ЧПУ ссылки на yii2

Tags: yii2, url

Не могу разобраться с ЧПУ ссылками на yii2. По идее все должно работать, но по видимому я что то упускаю....
Ниже приведу коды с проекта

eshop/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /web/fonts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule (.*)$ /web/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

eshop/web/.htaccess

```
#RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

eshop/config/web

```
....
'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'uvxfBK9B1S8ovnPJGbcAYyRrRCj56Qh3',
            'baseUrl' => '',
        ],
        ...
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'category/<id:\d+>/page/<page:\d+>' => 'category/view',
                'category/<id:\d+>' => 'category/view',
                'product/<id:\d+>' => 'product/view',
                'search' => 'category/search',
            ],
        ],
...
```

Обычные ссылки без ЧПУ работают то есть если я иду по ссылке *http://yii2.loc/eshop/web/index.php?r=category%2Fview&id=4*
то вижу элементы из выбранной категории но при активации ЧПУ т.е ссылка приобретает вид *http://yii2.loc/eshop/web/category/4* появляется **Object not found!**

а при загрузке начальной страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: А по ссылке `http://yii2.loc/eshop/web/category/4` что отображается?

Comment: нет только Object not found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем случае нужно чтобы обязательно был указан baseUrl

```
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
],
```

в корневом .htaccess
просто поставте

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /web/$1 [L]
```

и уберите из второго файла

```
RewriteBase /
```

лучше замените его на

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: добавил изменения как вы посоветовали и в тему ввел поправки но какой то злой рок творится опять Object not found!

Comment: я только заметил что у вас проект в папке eshop? но зачем?) дело в том что baseUrl выставляется как раз на ту директорию где лежит проект. в вашем случае надо конечно ставить 'baseUrl' => '/eshop' и в этом случае проект будет доступен по адресу http://yii2.loc/eshop/ не надо никаких web (при моих настройках)

Comment: и не забудьте и .htaccess тоже поправить с учетом /eshop

Comment: Огромное спасибо бро помог убрал папку eshop и все заработало!